# Can't display UI Element on top of ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

I'm struggling to display a UI Element **on top** a ScrollViewer. This should be pretty straight forward but hasn't been. I would have expected this code to work:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Button>A</Button>
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="Scroller">
        <Viewbox>
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="White"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button>B</Button>
</Grid>
```

But when I zoom into the ScrollViewer, it is displayed on top of **both buttons**.

Video: [Behavior](https://imgur.com/a/jAKd9Eq)
Image: [Desired vs Actual Behavior](https://imgur.com/a/qd31ogs)
Code: [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://github.com/Zev-G/UWP-ScrollViewer-Issue)

Comment: Why have a Grid if you're not going to assign rows and/or columns?

Comment: @ZevG: I guess "above" means "on top" in this case. The second `Button` should display on top of the `ScrollViewer` using the above markup. Your issue cannot be reproduced. Make sure you are not applying some custom `Style` to the `Button` which causes it to be invisible. Try with another type of control for example. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original code pretty much works. And, in fact, other answerers were able to run my code and have it work. The issue ended up being purely styling, if you look at this example: https://imgur.com/a/cM3aAI0, it's clear that the button is being shown but has a transparent background. So, for me to fix this all I had to do was this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="Scroller">
        <Viewbox>
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Yellow"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Background="Black" Height="120" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left">B</Button>
    <Button Height="50" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">A</Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

If you want the button to floating on other controls, then you should render the button later than other controls. Please put the buttons control under the `ScrollViewer` in the `Grid`.

Please try the following code:

```
  <Grid>
  <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="Scroller">
      <Viewbox>
          <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Yellow"/>
      </Viewbox>
  </ScrollViewer>
  <Button Height="120" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left">B</Button>
  <Button Height="50" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">A</Button>
</Grid>
```

How it looks like:
[image]

I test this in UWP project. The code also works in WinUI3 project.

**Old:**

Please try to set [RowDefinitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowdefinitions?view=winrt-22621) for the Grid and place UIElements into different Rows.

Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Button Grid.Row="0">A</Button>
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="Scroller">
     <Viewbox>
         <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="White"/>
     </Viewbox>
 </ScrollViewer>
 <Button Grid.Row="2">B</Button>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this if you want the second `Button` to appear on top of the `ScrollViewer`...?

Comment: The OP said **above**, so indeed there're might be missing row definitions for top and bottom buttons

Comment: I guess the OP means "on top".

Comment: Yes--sorry, meant on top (was in title but not description). Updated the question

Comment: @ZevG Could you please share more details about the expected behavior you want to get? Maybe an image or something else. The video you share just shows the current behavior. Do you want to show the button floating over the ScrollViewer?

Comment: Yes, I would like the button "floating" on top of the ScrollViewer. I added an additional image that will hopefully clear up any confusion. Thak you for the time this has been a pretty frustrating issue.

Comment: @ZevG I got your point. Actually you just need to make sure the buttons are rendered later than the ScrollViewer. I've updated my answer. Please check it for details.

Comment: Here's what I get when I run that exact code: https://imgur.com/a/cM3aAI0
If you look closely, you can see the B, but overall the button is invisible. Update: if I set the background of the button to be black this fixes everything. Must be some weird styling! Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

The second `Button` should display *on top* of the `ScrollViewer` using the markup you have posted markup.

Make sure that you are not applying some custom `Style` to the `Button` which causes it to be invisible.

Here is a complete example of a window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="WinUIApp.BlankWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button>A</Button>
        <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="Scroller">
            <Viewbox>
                <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="White"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center">B</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And how it looks on the screen:

[image]

Comment: So odd, if I create an entirely new project and paste in that code it doesn't work. I'll put up a (hopefully) reproducible example on Github a bit later today and also share a video of the behavior I get. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Ok I've gone ahead and added a video and an example project showcasing the issue. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Did you try my example? Do you get the same results as me?

Comment: Your issue cannot still not reproduced. The "B" button is visible on top of the `ScrollViewer`, just as expected.

Comment: You mean when you run the code in the Github link you see the button on top? Not entirely sure what you mean by "cannot still not".

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Okay, interesting. I'll try a few things, this might be an issue with my install of Visual Studio and UWP/WinUI then. This seems strange.